# XCTest: Tests are never run

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, unit-testing, xctest

I am trying to run XCTest Unit Tests but they seem to never get run. Even when I delete all my tests and start with a blank slate by adding the default test stubs as per [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-test_navigator/AddingTestBundles/AddingTestBundles.html) they won't run.

Using Product->Test seems to builds everything properly, the toolbar tells me it is "Testing...", but nothing happens. Even when clicking a single test in the gutter, the toolbar says "Testing..." and then reverts to normal after a few seconds. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does it work in a brand-new project? If so, something's wrong with your project settings.

Comment: I ended up having to create a new project. So it seems that something was indeed wrong with the settings but I have no idea what.

Comment: Now you can start comparing settings between projects.

Comment: Is the best way to do that just to compare by eye each tab of the project settings?

Comment: I'm afraid so. You might get lucky by filtering them for "test"